# Is using jQuery post method safe?

Tags: php, jquery, post, methods, pdo

I am looking at the best way to do validation and I keep coming back to using jQuery to validate and then if the validation is all good then using jQuery's post method to post the data to another php file which then goes through a PDO query into my DB.

My question is: Is it safe enough to use jQuery post or is there another, safer way of doing this? I was looking at php for my validation but you can't get the same effects such as changing the border colour of the input box to red or things like that.

Any advice would be great or if you know any other ways to approach it!

---

Yes I am validating on both sides but I am just wondering about is there a better method instead of using jQuery post. I am validation using jQuery first, then that gets sent to my php script where it is also validated and checked and then inserted into database using PDO.

The thing about using jQuery post is that it displays all the fields that are required by my page (e.g. the user can open up my js file and see what fields are being sent and where they are being sent!) where as using php would somewhat hide them. Thats all I am concerned about.

Comment: As is always repeated: NO, browser side validation is done by the user's browser, for the user, and doesn't protect your server.

Comment: What do you mean "safe"? If you validate data client side (even with AJAX) you still have to validate it again when it's submitted.

Comment: You **always** need to validate the user input on the server.

Comment: Your user can send whatever he wants to your server. There is no 'safe' client side validation that exists

Answer (score 1):

jQuery validation and php validation are two separate things. One is on the client side and another is on the server.

I am not sure what you mean by safe but just using client side validation is not enough. You must have server side validation set up.

The advantage of using client side validation though you will have server side validation set up is.

1. Reduce the network traffic (The number of requests which go the
   server).
2. Show validation messages without reloading the page. Like
   the ones you are talking about.